# Map in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a schema in Mongoose that have a map (object, associative array, key-value pairs), but no success so far.
The documents of my schema must be something like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("..."),
    "groups"
    {
        "groupA":
        {
            "value1": "...",
            "value2": "..."
        },
        "groupB":
        {
            "value3": "...",
        },
        "groupC":
        {
            "value4": "...",
            "value5": "...",
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

**groups** is as object with a *variable number of keys*. I don't know those keys ahead of time as it'll be create by the user.
Every entry in groups is another object. As before, I don't know the key identifiers, but I know that the values are *String* (or Boolean, or Number, doesn't matter).
Of course, those keys are *Strings*.

Is it even possible (is there anyway to build such schema/model) in Mongoose?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Best practice is to keep any dynamic data out of your field names. The typical approach for a use case like this is to make `groups` an array and move the name of the group into a `name` field of the contained objects.  Then you can use the `Mixed` type to contain the user-defined set of values:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("..."),
    "groups":
    [
        {
            name: "groupA",
            values: {
                "value1": "...",
                "value2": "..."
            }
        },
        {
            name: "groupB",
            values: {
                "value3": "..."
            }
        },
        {
            name: "groupC",
            values: {
                "value4": "...",
                "value5": "..."
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

You'd define the schema as:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    groups: [{
        name: String,
        values: Schema.Types.Mixed
    }]
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate an schema based on your example?

Comment: @NemoStein See edit. Updated to include the schema and make the values flexible as well.

Comment: As I can tell by yours and Mark's answers, what I want isn't possible, right?

Comment: @NemoStein You can use your original schema by defining it as `groups: Mixed`, but with dynamic keys, querying it will be a pain.

Comment: As both answers ATM are similar, and understanding that what I want to do isn't possible, I'll choose the first (this one) as correct.

Comment: "Best practice is to keep any dynamic data out of your field names .." do you have a reference for that?

Answer (score 13):

Map is supported from version 5.1 - 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps

Answer (score 4):

Looks like somebody made a plugin, Hooray!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-map

Once you install and configure according to the readme you can just do `{groups:[MongooseMap]}...`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    groups: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed]
});
```

Reference: [Mongoose Schema Types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

Edit, given my comments below, and riffing on the answer before mine, let's assume that all values are of type string (I had understood that they might be anything):

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    groups:[{
        name: String,
        values:[String]
    }]
});
```

Edit #2: Assuming that "value1" is a placeholder for some more meaningful name and assuming that the number of member names is finite, as long as they are not required, then you can put them all in your schema, so instead of the array version, you should be able to do this:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    groups:[{
        name: String,
        value1: String,
        value2: String,
        value3: String,
        value4: String,
        value5: String
    }]
});
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there is no type checking, this means that I can store anything on it, but I need a well defined structure.

Comment: But you are allowing users to put in variably shaped objects of random stuff. What are you going to be able to type-check in the scenario as you have laid it out??

Comment: Oh! Type is always something you know, for example string...  Let me edit my answer.

Comment: The problem with this approach is the "name" field. And my "ValueX" isn't a placeholder... The number of sub entries is variable too...